# python tkinter calender, placing the numbers

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, calendar, tkinter

I am creating a python program that uses tkinter to display a yearly calendar.

But, I stumbled across this problem - every time someone changes the month, the days obviously have to rearrange themselves inside my grid. How do I achieve this? For example, May 1 2014 begins on a Wednesday. Since my calendar has cols 0-10 and my calendar is rows 2-7 and cols 2-8, I would want the numbers to begin at row=2, col=6 and the 31st at row=6, col=8.

How could I do this? Any help or suggestions would be welcome. Especially since so far I think each element needs to be a label and each label needs to have its own name. Or, theres probably some other widget in tkinter that I don't know about that solves this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you post a code snippet? I'm not sure I get the question, but my first thought would be to generate a grid with `tk.Labels` assigned to each spot, and keep references to them in a list (or 2-D list). Then, when you need to update, just call

```
self.labels[i][j].config(text='foo')
```

Then you'd loop over `i` and `j` to set the values depending on how the calendar is laid out.

**Edit:**
No, I wouldn't hard-code it, it should be straightforward to do with a loop, e.g.:

```
import math

# Initialize the calendar matrix
cal = []
for i in range(5): # 5 weeks
    cal.append([])
    for j in range(7): # 7 days per week
        cal[i].append('')

# Set the calendar for some month
start = 3 # Wed
for day in range(31):
    row = math.floor( (day+start) / 7)
    col = (day+start) - 7*row
    cal[row][col] = str(day+1)

print(cal)
```

which spits out

```
[['', '', '', '1', '2', '3', '4'], ['5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11'], ['12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18'], ['19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25'], ['26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '']]
```

though in the GUI of course, you'd want to have a matrix of `tk.Label` or whatever.

Comment: So I should just waste my time writing down self.dayslot1, self.dayslot2, self.dayslot3, ... ? I'm not saying your answer is bad, I just was hoping for a more 'typing friendly' answer though. But still, an answer is an answer, and it helps so...